Rendering an image from Firebase Storage in React Native Expo
My goal is to render multiple images from Firebase Storage and display them in my React Native (Expo-managed) app. The images are stored in folders for each 'post' or 'report', but some posts may have no images and some may have multiple. My current code does not display the image, but there aren't any errors either. The download URL outputted in the getImg function is correct (upon testing).
I suspect the issue may be that the getImg function isn't completing in time (there needs to be a promise), but I'm not completely sure.
My current code:
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const getImg = (path) => {
        getDownloadURL(sRef(storage, 'reports/' + path)).then((url) => {
            return url;
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPosts = () => {
            const postRef = ref(db, 'reports');
            const fetched = [];
        
            onValue(postRef, (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach((post) => {
                    const report = post.val();
                    report.key = post.key;

                    for (let i = 0; i < report.images.length; i++) {
                        // here i am replacing the name of the file with the download URL
                        report.images[i] = getImg(report.key + "/" + report.images[i]);
                    }

                    fetched.push(report);
                }); 
                setPosts(fetched);
                setLoading(false);
            })
        }
        fetchPosts();
    }, [start]);

And part of the output:
<View style={styles.posts}>
   {posts.map(post => (
      <Pressable key={post.key} style={[styles.card, cardTheme]} onPress={() => {
         navigation.navigate('Report', {post: post});
      }}>
         <Text style={[styles.cardTitle, textTheme]}>{post.location}</Text>
         {post.images.length > 0 ? (
            <View style={styles.cardImages}>
               {post.images.map((image, index) => {
                  <Image key={index} source={{uri: post.images[index]}} style={styles.cardImage} />
               })}
            </View>
          ) : null}
         <Text style={styles.cardDate}>{post.date}</Text>
      </Pressable>
   ))}
</View>

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

You are correct in that you are not waiting for the getImg() promise to resolve

Also, onValue() is for subscribing to changes. You probably meant to use get() instead. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once
